# ArrayUtils cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, import

Im trying to use ArrayUtils to remove an item from an array, but i keep getting the error:

```
ArrayUtils cannot be resolvedJava(570425394)
```

This is what the method looks like:

```
public void removeCard(int index) {
        ArrayUtils.remove(this.cardPaths, index);
    }
```

I have tried importing org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils, but that gives me the error:

```
The type org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils is not accessibleJava(16778666)
```

Adding the dependency to the pom.xml file also did not resolve anything

I am using Java 14.0.1, Apache Maven 3.5.2 and Visual Studio Code

Comment: Have you added lang3 dependency provided by apache. If already added then try running command  `mvn clean install`

Comment: `<dependency><groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId><artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId><version>3.9</version></dependency>`. Clean build your maven

Comment: @Silverfang running mvn clean install works :) thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Note that your code doesn't do anything.

The `remove` method returns **a new array** - remove has no side effects; if you ignore what it returns, it doesn't do anything but waste some CPU and memory resources. Presumably you want:

`this.cardPaths = ArrayUtils.remove(this.cardPaths, index);`

furthermore, arrays as a concept are convoluted (they don't toString well, they can't grow or shrink). If you want an array-like concept that allows you to add and remove things, java already has this, it's called `ArrayList`. Then you don't *need* lang3 in the first place:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Deck {
    private List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();

    public void removeCard(int idx) {
        return cards.remove(idx);
    }
}
```